# Compare keys in a Map with elements in a List in java

Tags: java, list, exception, arraylist, hashmap

I have a static `HashMap <Integer, String>` and an `Arraylist<Integer>`.

```
public static final HashMap<Integer, String> CONSTANT_MAP =
    (HashMap<Integer, String>) Collections.unmodifiableMap(new HashMap<Integer, String>() {
        {
            put(28, "Action");
            put(12, "Adventure");
            put(16, "Animation");
            put(35, "Comedy");
            put(80, "Crime");
            put(99, "Documentary");
            put(18, "Drama");
            put(10751, "Family");
            put(14, "Fantasy");
            put(36, "History");
            put(27, "Horror");
            put(10402, "Music");
            put(9648, "Mystery");
            put(10749, "Romance");
            put(878, "Science Fiction");
            put(10770, "TV Movie");
            put(53, "Thriller");
            put(10752, "War");
            put(37, "Western");
        }
    });
```

I need a method that would compare `HashMap` *keys* with `ArrayList` *elements*. If the keys are equal, the `Hashmap` value should be put to a separate `ArrayList` and be returned.

I tried the following, but it doesn't work. I get `ExceptionInInitializerError`.

```
public static ArrayList<String> getGender(ArrayList<Integer> arrayList, HashMap<Integer, String> hashMap) {
    ArrayList<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Map.Entry m : hashMap.entrySet()) {
        if (arrayList.contains(m.getValue()))
            resultList = (ArrayList<String>) m.getValue();
    }
    return resultList;
}
```

Comment: By the way, `Map.of` is simpler syntax for instantiating a non-modifiable map.

Comment: I think you meant to name your method `getGenre()`, not `getGender()`.

Answer (score 3):

> I get `ExceptionInInitializerError`

This error is triggered by an *exception* that occur during initialization of a `static` field or while executing a *static initializer block*. A quote from the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError.html):

> An `ExceptionInInitializerError` is thrown to indicate that an exception occurred during evaluation of a static initializer or the initializer for a static variable.

In this case, you are trying to typecast a map returned by `unmodifiableMap()` to `HashMap` and this casting fails. It can't succeed because `unmodifiableMap()` is meant to wrap any implementation of the `Map` interface (`TreeMap`, `LinkedHashMap`, etc.). And this method returns an instance of class `UnmodifiableMap` which implements `Map` interface (i.e. it overrides all required methods) and maintains a variable of type `Map` (*a wrapped map that was passed as an argument*) and delegates to calls to it. Inherently `UnmodifiableMap` and `HashMap` are *siblings*, they both implement `Map`, but they don't extend each other, therefore you can't cast between these types.

A **remedy**: [*write your code against interfaces*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface), not *concrete types*, and you'll be fine. `CONSTANT_MAP` should be of type `Map`, not `HashMap` (by the way, I suggest to use more meaningful name like `ganreById`). Similarly, an argument of your method should be a `List`, not `ArrayList`.

> I need a method that would compare `HashMap` keys with `ArrayList` elements. If the keys are equal the `Hashmap` value should be put to a separate `ArrayList` and be returned.

Firstly, judging by the contents of the map I believe you've misspelled the method name, and you meant `genre`, not `gender`. In the code below I've changed it, as well as parameter-names (*sure, names are totally up to you, it's only an example, but keep in mind that they have a huge impact on the readability of the code and hence important*) and parameter types are changed to be the types of interfaces `List` and `Map`.

The most efficient way to approach this task is to iterate over the *list* and check whether a particular *element* is contained in the *map*.

Not the opposite like you've done in your code because `contains()` check is **costful** on a *list* (*you need to walk through all the elements to find  out if the matching element exists*), it's **O(n)** time if you're familiar with *Big O* notation. Conversely, `containsKey()` check on a `HashMap` is almost instant - **O(1)**.

If the matching key exist, the value associated with it will get added to the resulting list.

```
public static List<String> getGenre(List<Integer> ids, 
                                    Map<Integer, String> genreById) {

    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Integer id: ids) {
        if (genreById.containsKey(id))
            result.add(genreById.get(id));
    }
    return result;
}
```

***Sidenotes:***

- If this method resides in the same class where the *map* is defined as a static field, passing it as parameter is *redundant*.
- You can substitute double-curly braces initialization (*which isn't considered to be a good practice*) with the static method [`Map.ofEntries()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#ofEntries(java.util.Map.Entry...)) accessible with Java 9. It returns a map which is already unmodifiable, so there will be no need to wrap it with `Collections.unmodifiableMap()`.

Comment: @Alex20280 You are welcome. By the way, which version of the JDK you're using? With Java 9 + you can use static method `Map.ofEntries()` for initialization.

Answer (score 1):

well, if you just want to check whether the keys in hashmap is equal to the arraylist, you could use `hashMap.keySet().equals(new HashSet<Integer>(arrayList))`, and then use `hashMap.values()` to get all the values.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Alexander Ivanchenko correctly identifies the cause of the exception you're seeing (so you should accept his answer!).  My answer talks below talks about other problems with your code.

---

Your hashmap contains values that are Strings:

```
    HashMap<Integer, String> hashMap
```

therefore

```
    m.getValue()
```

is a String, and therefore you cannot cast it to an ArrayList of Strings

```
    resultList = (ArrayList<String>) m.getValue();
```

I think what you want is to accumulate values in your result list:

```
   resultList.add(m.getValue());
```

Additionally, as pointed out by @racraman, this comparison is problematic:

```
   if (arrayList.contains(m.getValue())
```

The list `arrayList` contains Integers; m.getValue() is a String; I am surprised this compiles at all. I think from the description you meant

```
    if (arrayList.contains(m.getKey())
```

so maybe was a transcription error when writing this post?

Comment: He also says he wants to compare the keys, but he’s comparing Integer to String in `if (arrayList.contains(m.getValue()))`

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, use the collections library to do the work for you:

```
public static List<String> getGenres(List<Integer> list, Map<Integer, String> map) {
    return map.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> list.contains(e.getKey()))
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Note also the use of the *abstract* type (eg `List`, `Map`, etc) in preference to the *concrete* type (eg `ArrayList`, `HashMap`, etc): see [The Liskov substitution principle (LSP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Note also the correction of the spelling error in the method name from `getGender` to `getGenres`, correcting both the semantic meaning and pluralisation - methods that return a collection should be named in the plural.